# About Spring Cloud Stream Application shutdown gracefully

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream as my service communication framework. But how can I shutdown the application without force terminating the working thread( produced @StreamListener).

I wrote some codes to meet requirement, but dependent on a Map. I don't think it a good resolution.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class MessageReceiverApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageReceiverApplication.class);

    private AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong();
    private Map<Long, Void> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void process(Message<String> message) {
        long count = atomicLong.incrementAndGet();
        try {
            map.put(count, null);
            logger.info("Processing:\t[{}]", count);
            Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(5000));
            logger.info("      Done:\t[{}]", count);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Terminate Exceptionally");
        } finally {
            map.remove(count);
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("Start listening");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Closing...");
        while(map.size() > 0) {
            logger.warn("Waiting for Stream job done");
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageReceiverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In this example, I start application by "java -jar", and CTRL+C to terminate the application. The application will terminate until the process() method finished, because of `while(map.size() > 0)` to check the Stream Listener Thread.
I'm wondering if there is a more graceful way to shutdown the thread without Interrupt the code within @StreamListener. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you possibly explain what you're trying to accomplish? Also, I am not seeing any termination code, so I am confused a bit

Comment: I start application by "java -jar", and CTRL+C to terminate the application. In process() method, I put a signal into the Map on top and remove the signal on bottom. When shutdown instruction comes, I can get to know if any thread is working via the map.size().

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to check whether the method annotated by @StreamListener  finished, because it cause Code Invasion issue.

Comment: @Aura Have you found a better way? i'm having same issue of needing kafka consumers to shut down gracefully. Note that this is not enough, you want to have the consumer commit offset to zookeeper before it dies otherwise you will reprocess these messages

Comment: @AmitGoldstein, finally I wrote an aspect to cross-cut all of the `@StreamListener`.